# How does process switch take place in VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, task-switching

For a normal standalone host, different processes do context switching using the scheduler. E.g., say there is Process 1 and Process 2, then control goes from Process 1 to Scheduler, and then from Scheduler to Process 2 which then executes till it gives back control to the Scheduler for scheduling another process.

I want to know how this switch, from Process 1 to Process 2, take place in a VM? Does VM call `VM_EXIT()` every time there is a process switch between two processes inside a VM? or the host scheduler has something to do with process switch?

AFAIK, the host OS views the VM as a single process. Could someone please point out to some hints where I could get these doubts cleared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual machines don't understand what's going on inside, they are just simulating hardware.

There are 3 basic methods of VM simulation. The most obvious one is hardware emulation, which is what Bochs does. It's just simulating x86-compatible PC programmatically, without any deeper magic behind it. PC is a machine for processing data, so Bochs just uses host OS to collect input data and feeds it to emulated virtual devices, then reads output data from those devices and uses host to present it. This is exactly what console emulators and similar programs do. Bochs doesn't know what happens inside the VM, it works on bare emulated hardware. The concept of processes is too abstract for it, it doesn't have to care for such things -  just hardware emulation.

Second kind of VM is what was common before hardware-accelerated virtualization was introduced. Bochs-style emulation is slow, because it's interpreting machine code byte by byte. Running bare bytecode is impossible in a running OS due to the way CPUs work (and they work like that for a good reason), but an application can take a chunk of bytecode and edit it to make it safe for executing in a host OS, then execute it as its own code. The editing stage serves two purposes: it sanitizes code to make running it possible and connects simulated I/O devices to appropriate data sources/targets of the host. Still, nothing like processes exists for a VM, it's just pseudo-emulating code on a physical CPU, pretending it's the program's code.

Finally, the third kind of VMs is hardware-accelerated virtualized VMs. It requires support in hardware, but all modern CPUs have it. It's just about doing what I said is impossible before: running low-level code in parallel to the host OS. The thing is, if you have it built into the CPU, you can let it handle the code properly. It will create a sandbox environment for that code, giving the host control over that sandbox. This way the VM code is executed even closer to the hardware, thus it works faster. It's also closer to using the hardware ring system, but still doesn't introduce the exact concept of processes. These are always handled by guest OSes. But in the hardware-accelerated VMs you can really see something similar to context switching like on host. Other kinds of VMs always run as user-level programs.

Comment: For QEMU/KVM (third kind of VM), if I have two processes- Firefox and VLC running in Guest, and There takes place a context switch from VLC to firefox, how does this switch and the switch between the VM process and other host processes at Host Machine level inter-relate? Is it correct to say that VLC-Firefox switch is independent of VM-other_host_process switch? Since VLC-Firefox switch takes place in a sandbox CPU environment?

Comment: You are right, those are completely independent. Switching processes in a VM shouldn't affect host and vice versa (except for performance of course - higher CPU load in host will affect guest's performance)

Answer (score 0):

Process switching inside a VM takes place the same way it takes place on a normal machine. The OS simply changes which process it's working on. The host doesn't know or care what's going on inside the VM -- what difference does it make?

Comment: Well, it doesn’t make any difference if virtual process 1 calls a system function; especially if it’s a blocking one, like “pause” or “read”. But what if process 1 is just running up CPU time, doing lots of computations without any I/O or any other external interaction? How does the guest OS scheduler (kernel) get control back? Does it use a host system function such as “alarm” to regain control periodically? Or does the hardware-accelerated virtualization allow clock interrupts that occur while the VM is running to be handled by the guest kernel rather than the host kernel?

Comment: @Scott The same way it takes place on a normal machine from the point of view of the guest. It requests clock interrupts and as far as it can tell, it gets them. The host simulates these clock interrupts the same way it simulates everything else the guest needs.

Comment: How can the host simulate an interrupt if the host is not running? Let’s assume the guest executes a certain process... this process calculates the answer for everything so it takes X years for the process to end/make a syscall what-eves... There need to be a REAL clock interrupt that will make sure the kernel is not stuck on that process... the problem is that if you get a clock interrupt the host should handle it... are there two separate clocks? One for the guest (possibly APICv) and the second is the actual clock that interrupts the hypervisor?

Comment: The guest and host work completely separately. The VM software requests to run or not run as it needs and the host hardware implements that using clock interrupts as necessary. The guest's OS asks the "guest hardware" to give it a clock interrupt (or whatever) as necessary and the VM software (running in the host like any other process) gives it simulated interrupts as needed.